# unity : How to change the default behaviour of the touchpad/trackpad in laptop?

Tags: unity, multitouch

I'm using unity on my laptop. Normally, i can customize my touchpad in most of 3d app but in unity i can't find a way to do it ? is it possible to customize it at user level without hard coding it ?

I just want the touchpad to behave like most app : 2 fingers pinch to zoom, 2 fingers drag to rotate view etc.

Comment: Is your question "How to implement 2-finger pinch to zoom" or "Hoe to implement 2-finger drag to rotate view'? Those are not customizations of the touchpad, those are new game mechanics you would add to your game with a script that processes the input gestures into camera movements.

Comment: Sorry i mean not in the game, i will use it will edit the 3d scene. (Not at 'run' time but while i work on unity scene.)